# I am trying to use react context api with react native class components but getting an error undefined provider.default.consumer

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am creating a component called provider to store my data

```
import React from "react";

export const MyContext = React.createContext();

export class MyProvider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isAuthenticated: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext.Provider
        value={{
          state: this.state,
          changeAuthState: value => this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true })
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </MyContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to consume that data from a nested component called add photo so when the user is done with the account setup it will change the data to authenticated = true and show the main stack

```
//addPhoto.js
import Provider from "../../../provider";

export default class AddPhoto extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      image: null
    };
  }

  
  render() {
   
    return (
      <Provider.Consumer>
        {
          (context = () => (
            <View style={styles.conatiner}>
              <View style={styles.authIocn}>
                <SimpleLineIcons name="camera" size={wp("30%")} />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={styles.headerText}>Add Profile Photo</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.paragraph}>
                <Text style={styles.paragraphText}>
                  Add a profile photo so your friends know its you.
                </Text>
              </View>
              <Button block style={styles.button} onPress={this._pickImage}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Add a Photo</Text>
              </Button>
              <View style={styles.skipButtonView}>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                  <Text style={styles.skipButtonText}>Skip</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
          ))
        }
      </Provider.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

getting error typeError: undefined is not an object evaluating  ('_provider.default.Consumer')

Comment: Ciao, may I see the line where you import Context?

Comment: I updated the question added the import

Comment: Wait, what React version are you using?

Comment: "react": "~16.11.0", "react-native": "~0.62.2"

Comment: Ok so why you are using `constructor`? Hooks implementation are really different from React pre-Hooks. Check [this](https://medium.com/crowdbotics/build-a-react-native-app-with-react-hooks-5498e1d5fdf6).

Comment: So you are saying the class version of context is deprecated ? ii'm just more comfortable with classes than hooks so i figured i'll use the class version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to export the Provider class and context from provider.js

```
import React from "react";

const MyContext = React.createContext();

class Provider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
      isAuthenticated: "false"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext.Provider
        value={{
          state: this.state,
          changeAuthState: value => this.setState({ isAuthenticated: value })
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </MyContext.Provider>
    );
   }
 }
 export { Provider, MyContext };
```

Then, i needed to wrap my app.js in the provider

```
 import { Provider } from "./provider";

return (
          <Provider>
            <NavigationContainer>
              {signedIn ? (
                <TabStack.Navigator
                  barStyle={{
                    backgroundColor: "#15212B",
                    borderColor: "#B0B8B3",
                    borderTopWidth: hp("0.05")
                  }}
                >
                  <TabStack.Screen name={"Feed"} component={Feed} />
                  <TabStack.Screen name={"Discover"} component={Discover} />
                  <TabStack.Screen name={"Account"} component={Account} />
                </TabStack.Navigator>
              ) : (
                <AuthStack.Navigator headerMode={false}>
                  <AuthStack.Screen name={"SignUp"} component={SignUp} />
                  <AuthStack.Screen
                    name={"EmailOrPhone"}
                    component={EmailOrPhone}
                  />
                  <AuthStack.Screen name={"SignIn"} component={SignIn} />
                </AuthStack.Navigator>
              )}
            </NavigationContainer>
          </Provider>
        );
      }
    }
```

Then finally wrap my addPhoto.js file in the context

```
import { MyContext } from "../../../provider";

return (
  <MyContext.Consumer>
    {context => (
      <View style={styles.conatiner}>
        <View style={styles.authIocn}>
          <SimpleLineIcons name="camera" size={wp("30%")} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Text style={styles.headerText}>Add Profile Photo</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.paragraph}>
          <Text style={styles.paragraphText}>
            Add a profile photo so your friends know its you.
          </Text>
        </View>
        <Button block style={styles.button} onPress={this._pickImage}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Add a Photo</Text>
        </Button>
        <View style={styles.skipButtonView}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.skipButtonText}>Skip</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    )}
  </MyContext.Consumer>
);
  }}
```